# Maven compiler plugin null pointer

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem during run of my tests by terminal. I need to run mvn install, but I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project ProjectName: Fatal error compiling: CompilerException: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project ProjectName: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

I tried to run it with different versions of compiler. When running tests by testNG in Eclipse everything works fine. The problem occurs when running through terminal. These are cucumber tests of mobile application. Runner uses Appium.

Comment: Please post a minimal version of your pom.xml that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you running on JDK 9 / JDK 10? Which version of Maven are you using?

Comment: I am using JDK 9.0.4. 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0". xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance". xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">. 
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>. 

  <groupId>group</groupId>. 
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>. 
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>. 
  <packaging>jar</packaging>. 
  <name>projectName</name>. 
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>.

Answer (score 21):

I was also getting `Fatal error compiling: CompilerException: NullPointerException` when running a maven 3.3.9 compile under JDK 11.
I switched to JDK 8 and no longer got the `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 12):

There's an open issue in Maven Compiler Plugin, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-346 .

The underlying problem is usually caused by a compiler error that gets masked. To find out the compiler error, pass `-Dmaven.compiler.forceJavacCompilerUse=true` to the `mvn` command line.
After fixing the compiler error, the problem goes away.

Comment: This worked for me.  Added and then was able to see/fix the compile errors. In any case, the compile plug-in shouldn't be throwing NPE

Answer (score 9):

It happens when maven compiler plugin can't find some required part of your source code.

Let me tell you my case:

1. I created a spring boot application and wanted to test it
2. So I created another maven module to create an API for automated GUI tests
3. [spring-boot-maven-plugin](/questions/tagged/spring-boot-maven-plugin) overrides the way jars are created so the directories inside the .jar change so I had to tune the [maven-jar-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jar-plugin) to generate the jar for me
4. I forgot to include a package (service) in this plugin so the same error you have appeared

So... I included the package and it worked

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>inventarios.Inventarios</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--to be imported on other projects-->
                        <classifier>app-to-import</classifier>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/desktop/*</include>
                            <include>**/desktop/navigation/*</include>
                            <include>**/service/*</include> <!--the package I forgot-->
                            <include>**/util/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Another suggestion I found while searching for the [bug in JDK classes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216202) was to add on the compiler plugin the configuration option `forceJavacCompilerUse`

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The 2nd suggestion about adding <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse> forced the maven/java system to list some error messages

Comment: Second suggestion: <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse> worked for me. Thanks.