# How can I compile a maven project from GitHub

Tags: maven, github, compiler-errors

I'm trying to download and compiler an open-source project from GitHub but with no success.

I was trying to compile Apache's Pulsar, as recently they pushed a vulnerability fix I need, but the new version is not out yet.

So in the meantime I wanted to compile it myself and when it is finally out I'll go back to their official release.

Is that possible?

It's a Maven project so from what I read I need to use '`maven package`' but it failed during tests' stage because of `noClassDefFound` if I'm not mistaken.
I tried two different versions from their GitHub but it also fails there.

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is similar to [`apache/pulsar` issue 8020](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/8020), which seems resolved at the time.

Check also [`apache/pulsar` issue 13126](https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/13126) which suggests  adding `-Dmaven.compiler.forceJavacCompilerUse=true` to the maven command line, because of an [opened maven issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70739212/6309).

All those assume that you are using `mvn package`, not '`maven package`'.

Comment: Thank for the help, I'll try to do so when I return home. Just a question - is there a difference between maven package and mvn package? I think I just pressed the Maven button and chose package.

Comment: @MarkFesenko In command line, that would be mvn , not maven. Through an IDE GUI, the button maven should trigger an mvn command, so it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

It's always mvn.

Make sure you have Java 8 or 11 and mvn the latest version.